# Find Path to Files containing specific word - How can I know which file in a directory contain the specific word that I want?

Tags: bash, git, shell, grep

I manage to find the word that I desire with the following command in a github repository

```
git log --all -p | grep 'abc'
```

`abc` is a word located in a specific file.

My question is how can I find the file path to the string that I desire? How can I know which file contain the word that I want which is `abc` ?

For example, doing the above command would get me

```
(this.b(),this.abc);
```

but I would like to know which exact folder and which exact file is this piece of string/code coming from.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
git grep -l 'abc'
```

Option [`-l`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-grep#Documentation/git-grep.txt--l) list file names where the pattern is found in the current (`HEAD`) commit.

Answer (score 1):

Just run

```
git log --all -p
```

This shows the output in the pager, usually `less`. You can search, scroll forward and backward.

To search the string, type <kbd>/</kbd> <kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Enter</kbd> (the `abc` here is a regular expression, not a literal string). Type <kbd>n</kbd> to find the next occurrence. When you have found one, you can scroll back with <kbd>b</kbd> and look at the patch text to see which file it is. (BTW, type  <kbd>Space</kbd> to scroll forward; type  <kbd>q</kbd> to exit the pager.)

Answer (score 1):

The following (tested with GNU `awk`) should be an approximation of what you want:

```
git log --all -p |
awk '/^diff --git / {files = $0}
     /^@@ /,/^(commit |diff --git )/ {if(index($0, "abc")) print files}'
```

We store the `diff --git` line in variable `files`. Then, if your string is found between the following line starting with `@@`  and the line starting with `commit`  or `diff --git` , the `files` variable is printed.

It is an approximation only because string `abc` could also be found in the `diff --git` or `commit` lines and also because `^@@` , `^diff --git`  or `^commit`  could be found in file contents.

More accurate solutions exist but they are more complicated and those I can think of cannot be 100% perfect.